# Laravel Vue Language Translation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

can someone show me a working example of vue-router together with vue-i18n , I am working with laravel and vue, had all my translations ready for laravel, now I converted them to javascript translations using laravel-vue-i18n-generator plugin

however when I go use them on my component.vue files, I get this warning http://prntscr.com/bkg9qo

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please upload code examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pretty old question, but this problem is really common. So for further views this is the answer!

in your `app.js` file import the 2 below :

`import VueInternalization from 'vue-i18n';`

`import Locales from './vue-i18n-locales.generated.js';`
(this will be generated through the artisan command `vue-i18n:generate`

and before the `const` declaration as of shown below I imported this forEach

```
Object.keys(Locales).forEach(function (lang) {
   Vue.locale(lang, Locales[lang])
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

And finally to set the locale I added the following lines to my `app.blade.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Vue.config.lang = '{{ app()->getLocale() }}';
</script>
```

Hope this helps!